# Openoffice convert number to date

Tags: openoffice.org

I am using Openoffice spreadsheet. I need to convert number (20121107) to date (2012-11-07).

I tried `'=YEAR(D2)&"-"&MONTH(D2)&"-"&DAY(D2)'`, but it didn't work.

Is there any function I can use to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using formulas by a two step approach:

a) split the number (assuming it is in in cell **A1**) into pieces
`=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1;4);"-";MID(A1;5;2);"-";RIGHT(A1;2))`
This gives you your date as a STRING in a cell.

b) Combine this with VALUE, like `=VALUE(CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1;4);"-";MID(A1;5;2);"-";RIGHT(A1;2)))`

This yields to a date number **41220** (from start of counting, as determined by `Tools>Options...>OpenOffice.org Calc>Calculate>Date`; mine is set to option '1899-12-30'). 
Now format as you like.